# How to Execute Python-Fu script from shell via Gimp

Tags: python, shell, gimp, python-fu

I'm trying to figure out a simple way to execute a Python-Fu script I wrote up that's working in single-threaded mode from the Python-Fu interpreter plugin of Gimp but will no longer work when refactored into its multiprocessing equivalent due to the Windows non POSIX / OS.Fork limitations that pop up in `Pool.map_async()`. As a work around I'm trying to invoke the script directly from the cmd shell but can't figure out the right command to get it done. I have the gimp bin directory on my PATH variable and am trying to get something achieved like the following...

```
c:\>gimp-console-2.8 --no-interface --batch "(python-fu execfile('myPyFuScript.py'))"
c:\>gimp-console-2.8 --no-interface --batch "myPyFuScript.py"
```

Is there a way to get Gimp to execute a python script using its Python-Fu module from a command issued at the Windows cmd shell?

Just for added background I'm taking inspiration from the following [documentation](http://www.gimp.org/docs/python/)...

> **GIMP Python Invocation from the Shell**
>
> All this means that you could
>   easily invoke a GIMP Python plug-in such as the one above directly
>   from your shell using the (plug-in-script- fu-eval …) evaluator:

```
gimp --no-interface --batch '(python-fu-console-echo RUN-NONINTERACTIVE "another string" 777 3.1416 (list 1 0 0))' '(gimp-quit 1)'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The string you pass GIMP after `--batch` is itself executed in script-fu .
The easy way to run a Python script there is to write a script-fu expression that will call your python procedure. For example:

```
gimp  -n --no-interface --batch "(python-fu-gradient-save-as-css  RUN-NONINTERACTIVE \"Sunrise\" \"/tmp/grad.css\")" --batch "(gimp-quit 1)"
```

Besides the use of the script-fu expression `"(python-fu-gradient-save-as-css  ... )"` you should note the following:

- the use of `-n` to ensure a it is run in  a new GIMP instance (maybe this is not needed at all - it did work for me here)
- Use of double quotes (`"`) to delimit string parameters in the script-fu string. Single quotes have different syntactic meaning in scheme/script-fu.
- the need to call `gimp-quit 1` - otherwise, even with `--no-interface --batch`, GIMP keeps running.

Since you will be calling GIMP from an outher Python script, escaping the `"` is a non-issue - but people calling it from the command prompt in Windows will have to find a creative way to do that. (Above, they are escaped in bash shell with a `\`)

That should answer your question. However, I will dig a little further:
unless the processing you are doing in your script is really heavy-weight, the overhead of calling a separate GIMP instance for each script invocation may be huge (I didn't measure the memory usage - it takes about 2 seconds per invocation on my i5 non SSD machine after the task is properly cached by the OS - so you might as well live with it).

But my approach to it, since performance is an issue, would be to write the GIMP-Python procedure to instantiate a XMLRPC (or [JSONRPC](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/json-rpc/)) server and the outer, controlling script to call the "real" procedures through RPC. Using XMLRPC in Python is easy - less than 10 lines boilerplate code you can mostly copy and paste directly from the module docs in  http://python.org. That way you could have a pool of GIMO process ready to perform your task, with a simple, fast RPC call (one GIMP per logical core, and you have to put some logic on the controlling script to round-robin/queue the calls, of course).